# Git log, display specific data (by regex) with specific color

Tags: git, colors, git-log

I use this command to display git log:

`git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all --pretty=format:'\''%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an%C(auto)%d %Creset%s'\'' --date=format:'%d.%m.%Y''`

As you can see, I use specific output format (with specific colors). In the console I see something like this:

`* 3eb268b 01.01.2019 username (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) CODE-123 Random commit message`

The question is next: how can I highlight this part: `CODE-123`?

I tried to use `grep`, but had no luck.

**EDITS**

1. CODE-123 is not constant string. It can be TEST-2121, PJ-21, etc.
2. CODE-123 is part of the commit message

Comment: This does not fix your problem ... but you are missing a `'` at the end of your command to make it work.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName however, thanks :)

Comment: I also get `--date=format:.>.%Y` after the commit message ... this is also not correct, or? so I think your `%Creset%s'\''` has one `'` too much ... and then you don't need the one on the end too.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName this is ok. This command is part of my zsh alias

Comment: Is `CODE-123` part ot the commit message?

Comment: Yes, `CODE-123` is the begining of the `%s` string (commit message subject)

Comment: @RomainValeri Is this `CODE-123` always the same string? Or does it occur only sometimes ... more information is needed :-)

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName Wow, sorry lol... I answered but I'm not the OP, this is a confusion ^^ And I would ask the same question to *Roman*.

Comment: @RomainValeri No problem, the OP can still see and answere my question ;-)

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName Hey, guys :) CODE-123 is not constant string. It can be TEST-2121, PJ-21, etc. That's why regex is great solution. Yes, CODE-123 is part of the commit message

Comment: @RomanSvyatnenko Ok, please edit your question and add this info too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got a working solution:

`git log --oneline --decorate --graph --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an%C(auto)%d %Creset%s' --date=format:%d.%m.%Y --color=always | grep --color=always -E '[A-Z]+-[0-9]+|$' | less -r`

Answer (score 2):

Although I get why you'd like to have this, I'd say **you can't do that with git log's pretty formats**.

The string you want to highlight is, as we already commented, *part of the `%s` placeholder* which holds the commit message subject (first line of the commit message).

And color codes in pretty formats are not that flexible, we don't get to make our own placeholders or cut parts of them.

Of course you could pipe your log to any **bash function** to modify the output, but there's unfortunately no doing this purely just with a `pretty` format.

Comment: I share the same opinion.

Comment: And what about pipes? What can I use to highlight text without losing git-log's colors?

Comment: @RomanSvyatnenko Yes, I'm pretty sure you could pipe it to a bash string manipulation function (although the "cost" would maybe outweight the benefits), but I'm unsure about the specifics and will let my estimated peers answer that part :-)